# Why are the items overflowing the fixed parent while the width is auto (flex)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

So, I have a container with display-style flex (nowrap) inside a fixed container. Every child has an auto-width setting as well as the parent and the wrapper. Somehow the content container shows the last part of the container as "extra space" while there is still content. When I set `overflow:hidden` on the content container it just cuts off the last part.

I found out that setting the parent to relative fixes the problem as well as setting a fixed width to the children. However, this will not work in the setting where I need it. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

[JSfiddle here!](https://jsfiddle.net/pub1mt09/)

[image]

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: unset;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: unset;
  transform: translateX(-175px);
}

.content-item {
  background: orange;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**When for example I set the childs to width 200px instead of auto:**
[image]

**When for example I set the position of the content container to relative instead of fixed:**
[image]

Both solutions wont work for me, since I need to be able to translate to the end of the content container, but instead it does not calculate the purple area from the first screenshot. So my question is, why is a part of the inside overflowing the container?

Comment: You have some funky stuff going on, and the desired output is not entirely clear. Could you post an image of how it looks when the other undesired styles "fix" the problem?

Comment: It's because you've set property `transform: translateX(-175px);` in `.content` class in css. Since the elements before it start out of the page  and already have space there, some space is left. Try reducing `translateX()` property and extra space won't be there.

Comment: Well Blind Spot, in fact chrome says the width of the container element is smaller then it actually is when i dont use any kind of transform. So it doesn't seem to help when I remove the transform. It just makes clear where the problem is located.

Comment: Wait, like you're worrying about that orange box chrome is displaying, what space you want to cover?

Comment: Well, the problem is that a translation of 100% is not 100% of the total width, but of the width minus the purple area. Also, when i use overflow hidden it just hides content, while every element has an auto width, which is strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  /*transform: translateX(-100%);*/
}

.content-item {
  background: orange;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="content-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's strange, this seems to work, untill your viewport is smaller then 992 pixels.

Comment: Please post a markup image (one you have illustrated over) of the issue at 992 pixels. The desired output is still a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry, i'm having a hard time expressing myself. I want the situation where every element had an auto-width, but still being able to see the full elment when i use for example overflow:hidden on the content container instead of being cut off for some reason.

Comment: @Johnenzone See edits. Give that a try. If you uncomment `transform: translateX(-100%);` the entire row goes off-screen as you mentioned in the comments up top. If this doesn't work for you, I'd suggest updating your question so that the issue is concise and can be easily understandable; to avoid getting it closed.

Comment: @Johnenzone Let me know.